# Get list of files from SharePoint folder by URL

Tags: development, csom, client

I've got a URL to a folder on Sharepoint, and all I need to do is get a list of the files in that folder.

When I use my browser to go to `https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/Planning/`, I automatically get redirected to `https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/Planning/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, and I get to see the files present in that folder.

Now I want to get that same list of files in my desktop application. Here's what I have so far:

```
using (var Context = new ClientContext(fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)) {
    AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default,
    Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password)
})
{
    var folder = Context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(fullUri.AbsolutePath);
    Context.Load(folder);
    Context.Load(folder.Files);
    Context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(folder.Files.Count);
    foreach (var file in folder.Files)
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

where `fullUri = new Uri("https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/Planning/");`.

Now this *appears* to work fine; `folder.Name` prints as "Planning", which is as expected; however, the `folder.Files.count` is always zero, 0.
But the browser shows that there is, indeed, a file present in that folder.

What am I doing wrong?!?

---

**Update:**

I've tried the REST request mentioned in the comments:

```
https://<name>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Organisation/Section/Planning')/Files
```

which returns the following XML (which doesn't seem to contain much either :-\):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://[name].sharepoint.com/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>a13a6953-4a31-4e76-a9ba-437e85261a43</id>
    <title />
    <updated>2018-03-16T17:08:04Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
</feed>
```

Comment: Not sure why CSOM isn't working as expected, but have you tried using REST instead? `https://<name>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Organisation/Section/Planning')/Files`

Comment: @wjervis: thanks for the tip; I've tried, but while that _appears_ to work, it also doesn’t yield anything interesting. I’ve included the response in the question.

Comment: It's a bit strange but the code seems to be ok. Did you try to retrieve ListItemAllFields property instead of Files? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's review the the url of documents library where files are stored: `https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/Planning/Forms/AllItems.aspx`
which corresponds to the following structure:

```
Organisation (root site)
        |
     Section (sub site)
            |
         Planning  (documents library)
            |
           (files)
```

In your example the context is getting initialized for the **root** site:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)))
{
}
```

since for

```
var fullUri = new Uri("https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/Planning/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
```

`fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` is getting resolved to site url: `https://<name>.sharepoint.com/`

In that case `Context.Web` points to the root site (`Organisation` in your case) and with this line

```
var folder = Context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(fullUri.AbsolutePath);
```

you are trying to retrieve the folder which is expected to be  located on the **current** web site, which apparently is not the case here since it resides under sub site (`Section`)

Given the requirements, in particular to retrieve file/file per absolute url, i would to propose the following solution:

```
  using (var rootCtx = new ClientContext(fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))) //1. init context for root site
  {
      rootCtx.Credentials = GetCredentials(userName, password);
      Uri webUri = Web.WebUrlFromPageUrlDirect(rootCtx, fullUri);  //2. resolve the proper web  
      using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
      {
           ctx.Credentials = GetCredentials(userName, password);

           var list = ctx.Web.GetList(fullUri.AbsolutePath); //3. get list where files reside
           ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
           ctx.ExecuteQuery();

           Console.WriteLine(list.RootFolder.Files.Count);
      }
  }
```

**Key points**:

- Client context for a proper web is getting initialized via
  [`Web.WebUrlFromPageUrlDirect` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.weburlfrompageurldirect.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [`Web.GetList` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getlist.aspx) is utilized to retrieve *target* library where
  files/folders reside

---

The same concerns REST API, the *valid context* needs to be provided as part of `service root url`.

So in your case, instead of endpoint:

```
https://<name>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Organisation/Section/Planning')/Files

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invalid context (root site)
```

it should be

```
https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Organisation/Section/Planning')/Files
```

or

```
https://<name>.sharepoint.com/Organisation/Section/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Planning')/Files
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, that was it.  Do you know why SharePoint didn’t give an error when I was asking for the wrong context? Or does SharePoint just not give error messages?

Comment: Martijn, good question but not sure why SharePoint does not raise error  in that case. Maybe because the provided container (sub site folder in this case) exist..

Comment: This looks like it will work for me, but I can't work out where GetCredentials comes from (ie. its namespace). It's not recognised by C#. I have installed the SharePointPnPCoreOnline nuget package and added  'using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;'